# How to hide and show a layout view using finger movement in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in Android Development. I am working on a dummy app which is use the same concept of **Bigo live app** (live broadcasting screen swipe animation). In my app I want to hide and show a layout containing some view. When I swipe from left to right then the current view will be hide and when I swipe vice versa then my hided view will be appear. All the work will work on my finger movement.
I already implemented Touch Listener.
Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Basically: create a new touch listener, create a bar on left/right side of the screen, and when it is touched and moved, you move the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried implementing this using [this library](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer). I added a fragment that plays a video and inside the layout of that fragment I added this sliding drawer and that also contains a fragment which will act as an overlay when the drawer is opened or closed. Let me explain how:

So I have a videofragment and this is the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".ui.activity.VLCActivity">


<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<!--</com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView>-->

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_video_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"></include>


<com.github.ali.android.client.customview.view.SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    custom:offsetDistance="20px"
    custom:stickTo="right">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/textchat"
            android:name="com.projects.kaarthick.mluitests.ui.fragments.TextChatFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.github.ali.android.client.customview.view.SlidingDrawer>
```

I added the sliding drawer inside my fragment layout and also added another fragment containing some content like a textview showing some dummy chat text like chat window of bigo live. The layout for the chat fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
tools:context="com.projects.kaarthick.mluitests.ui.fragments.TextChatFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Mike: Wow, that is great, \nSally: awesome!!!.\n Terry: Cool man! How did you do it?. \n Justin:Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Now in the video fragment, make sure it implements the SlidingDrawer.OnInteractListener and add these codes in onCreateView():

```
mSlidingDrawer = rootView.findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer);
mSlidingDrawer.setOnInteractListener(this);
mSlidingDrawer.openDrawer();//to show the fragment at start
```

These methods have to be overridden for custom actions:

```
@Override
public void onOpened()
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Slide left",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onClosed()
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Slide right",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is what I was able to achieve:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWjRk.gif)